# Prove that the following limit doesn't exist

Tags: limits

Show
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$$
does not exist.

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting a link. Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Try $y = ax^b$.

Comment: Take the paths $y=x^2$ and $y=x$

Comment: Try googling this kind of problem.

Comment: Take the paths $y = 0$ and $y = x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$f (x,0)=0$$
$$f (x,x^2)=\frac {1}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

If you're going over these kind of limits, you have probably heard of the *path test*.

If you can find two different paths leading to $(0,0)$ but where the limits along those paths are different, then the initial, two-variable limit does not exist.

**Hint**: looking at the powers of $x$ and $y$, try $y=x$ and $y=x^2$. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Try by evaluating the limit along the parabola $y=mx^2$ with $m\in\mathbb{R}$.  What do you obtain? The limit depends on $m$?